# Get Enriched MultiLineText Field value without loosing its HTML property and Display it without html tag using spfx pnp/sp

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, office-dev-pnp, reactjs

I need to get enriched multi line text field value of a list item in SharePoint online SPFX web-part and display the field value in a table column without loosing its html property also hiding html tag displaying along with the field value.

Currently I get all fields of a list item by using the code:

```
const siteweb = Web(this.props.site);
let item: [] = await siteweb.lists.getByTitle(this.props.list).items.getById(propKey[this.props.propertybagid]).fieldValuesAsText.get();
```

Comment: Why are you using "fieldValuesAsText" ? in your call? Is it a multiline rich text field? 
Or try fieldValuesAsHTML

Comment: i need to get the hyperlink field  values along with this that why i used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using React JS and getting the multi-line field text in HTML tags format then you can bind its value to `div` element as:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.multilineFieldVale}} />;
```

Where `this.state.multilineFieldVale` stores the value of your multi-line field.

**documentation**: [React DOM Elements - dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).